# BasicAuth Prompt won't show with Status 401

Tags: python, http, http-headers, tornado, basic-authentication

I don't see a password prompt in IE/Firefox even when I send the 401 status code with Tornado:-

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        self.set_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="users"')
        self.send_error(status_code=401)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/users/(\w+)", UserHandler),
],debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Moreover the WWW-Authenticate header won't show in the response headers. When I don't send the 401 status, it does show in the header but it doesn't show the password prompt still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works although I am not sure why.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        self.set_status(401)
        self.set_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Users')

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/users/(\w+)", UserHandler),
],debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution you found (using [`set_status()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_status) instead of `send_error()`) works because [`send_error()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.send_error) calls [`clear()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.clear), which "[r]esets all headers and content", as can be seen in [the source](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.send_error). It then calls [`write_error()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write_error) to send new content and headers based on the status code.

If you're fine with handling errors by setting all content and headers manually (or with your own methods), just never use `send_error()`.

I found that you can also modify `RequestHandler`'s methods to make `send_error()` work for you instead of against you. The `WWW-Authenticate` header is an expected part of any `401` response, so it would be nice if `send_error(401)` would automatically add it. That can be done by overriding `write_error()`:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        if status_code == 401:
            self.add_header(
                'WWW-Authenticate',
                'Basic realm=' + json.dumps(self.realm))  # adds quotes
        super(BaseHandler, self).write_error(status_code, **kwargs)

class UserHandler(BaseHandler):
    realm = 'Users'
    # ...
```